# Adding Custom Form Field

Tags: forms, input-fields

I have a tricky thing to solve. This would be used for fast food menu.

First field is pretty much Name of the Group ex "Choose the sauce" and other 2 fields (and 2 fields should aways exist and that's minimal ammount of fields/options) would be for ex "Tomato" and "Fish".

Now problem is that users could in theory add more fields for more options (however first 2 fields could not be removed) but others that could be added should be removable. But adding trash can next to only third one is looking weird.

[image]

Comment: are those two fields editable? or the categories for those two are always the same? Also, you have a drag handler, what does it mean? can users move the editable field above the fixed ones? If so, does it become fixed and the previous one becomes editable?

Comment: Yes you can change order of those with handler. And yes users can edit all of them on that moment and later when editing.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are trying to present something on the user interface that isn't consistent with the underlying business or technical requirements.

If the rule is that two items must be displayed for each option, then you shouldn't prevent the user from deleting any of the options if there are more than two available.

If the rule is that there must be two preset items that can't be deleted, then you would need to create additional rules that check for duplicates and track the preset items so that they are not removed even if their position is moved.

Currently the rule seems to be that there must be two items, but all items can be moved and all item values can be edited, and only the two positioned at the top can't be deleted. I suggest making the rules clearer so that you can design the corresponding interface and interaction behaviour to be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood the question is that there are always two options for each, but the user is allowed to add more options to each of the two.
Have you thought of visually separating them? E.g the upper part of the screen / UI is showing the "mandatory" options for each category, then visually separated on the lower end you allow the user to add "extra options". You could even make this more obvious by displaying a sentence to the user which explains that those are the extra options. In this case I don't think the trash can looks weird, but it actually makes sense then.